# Insert or replace 2 unique values

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm using sqlite in android app and I want to make insert in table by 2 unique row values. For example:

```
id| column1 | column2 | column3|
1.   1              2     3  
2.   2              3     4
```

Unique columns - COLUMN1 and COLUMN2

```
 INSERT OR REPLACE INTO HISTORY (id, column1, column2, column3) VALUES (null, 2, 3, 6);
```

But this query shouldn't works 'cause 1st and 2nd values isn't unique in table

Thnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, simply use the [`UNIQUE` constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp) when building your table:

```
CREATE TABLE History (
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    column1 INTEGER,
    column2 INTEGER,
    column3 INTEGER,
    UNIQUE (column1, column2));
```

Then if you try these `INSERT` statements:

```
INSERT INTO History (column1, column2, column3) VALUES (2, 3, 0);
INSERT INTO History (column1, column2, column3) VALUES (2, 3, 6);
```

The second will fail because `column1` and `column2` already exist.

Understand that if you use `INSERT OR REPLACE` in my example, the second statement will replace the first (no exception thrown).

---

> but how can i add unique to existed table?

Typically you would use `ALTER TABLE` to add a constraint to your existing tables, but SQLite does not allow this... However you can workaround this limitation:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX name ON History(column1, column2);
```

Comment: thanks, i will try it, but how can i add unique to existed table? alter table...? and i tried "create unique index...", but this not help.